# How to use short paths for importing in Nx Workspace?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have created an NX Workspace using Angular preset. Where I have one app and two libraries. Inside my app, I am trying to use shorter paths for import.

With my current approach inside my app, I can use short paths for all files and folders for my app only. Whenever I am trying to import any library inside my app getting this error - `Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations.`

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@extranet/leftbar": ["libs/extranet/leftbar/src/index.ts"],
            "@extranet/topbar": ["libs/extranet/topbar/src/index.ts"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

**App's - tsconfig.json**

```
compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["app/*"],
            "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
            "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"],
            "@config/*": ["app/configs/*"]
        }
}
```

**App's - tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
        "types": [],
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["app/*"],
            "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
            "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"],
            "@config/*": ["app/configs/*"]
        }
    },
    "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

**App's Module**

```
// Auth layout & Admin Layout imports
// These imports are working fine
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from '@core/layouts';
import { WithLeftbarLayoutComponent } from '@core/layouts';
import { WithoutLeftbarLayoutComponent } from '@core/layouts';

// Library imports for templates
// With these two imports I am getting error
import { ExtranetTopbarModule } from '@extranet/topbar';
import { ExtranetLeftbarModule } from '@extranet/leftbar';
```

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately tsconfig path's are overwritten when extended, instead of the array being extended. So when you provide paths in an app's tsconfig, it is overriding the paths in the base tsconfig, hence your libraries are not being found.

A workaround for this is to just copy the library paths from tsconfig.base.json, but there is nothing on the Nx side to get around this.

Comment: This saved me from hours of headaches today

Comment: You can try adding the paths to the base tsconfig itself, but that always ends up giving an annoying eslint error for @nrwl/enforce-boundaries. It's so annoying when you cannot do absolute imports within libraries unless you create them as libraries yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible by setting paths in tsconfig.base.json.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855976

Answer (score 1):

According to [TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), the following is what's going on behind the scenes

> ...the compiler searches for the tsconfig.json file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.

In that case you need a `tsconfig.json` file. So to integrate this with what Nx provides, You should create the following `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

And keep all of your other TS config in the `tsconfig.base.json` file.

Problem should be solved afterwards.